# noobs behind a proxy

Tags: noobs

I downloaded noobs 2.7, and inserted the sd card into the raspberry pi2.
I only see the Raspbian operating system because the raspberry is behind a proxy and can not connect to the internet.
How can i solve this problem and set a proxy for noobs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you see the Raspbian operating system? On your monitor connected to the raspi? What do you expect to see? No operating system?

Comment: you need to connect to a wifi network with internet by pressing `w` or clicking `wifi network`. if you don't have internet, ask to use a friends or something.

Comment: ok. I'll explain.

Comment: In the Raspberry.org website I read "NOOBS is an easy operating system installer which contains Raspbian. It also provides a selection of alternative operating systems which are then downloaded from the internet and installed."

Comment: I followed the procedure to put NOOBS on my SD card and started the raspberry PI. The installer starts, but the "list" is not there. There is only the possibility of choosing to install Raspbian.Where are the other choices? It is possible that it depends. The raspberry is already in the LAN behind a proxy. So you can not go on the internet if you do not configure the proxy. But where do I do it inside the installer?

Comment: I hope my problem is clear now

Comment: can you disable the proxy while you install the RPi software?